# imagemagick segmentation fault after apache graceful restart

Tags: apache, segmentation-fault, imagemagick, imagick, php-5.6

We are using ImageMagick via imagick to generate a file containing many SVG files in it. The script tries to make them fit as much as possible in order to avoid large empty spaces so it is kind of a heavy task.

Everything went OK until we decided to install netdata on the server to monitor it, we can't say netdata is the cause of this 100% but we're pretty sure this started after installing it.

Now after every apache graceful restart we're getting segmentation fault errors but ONLY when trying to generate a file with "multi color" SVGs, everything works ok when generating a file with "plain color" SVGs.

The problem disappears if we restart apache (sudo service httpd restart).
Our theory is that restarting apache grafecully leaves an apache child thread hanging and crashes when trying to use it or something.

We tried reinstalling ImageMagick and imagick but nothing changed, we stopped netdata since we noticed this and tried to debug using gbd (it ended up slowing apache and making it difficult to restart it) and we could not find anything useful. I'm thinking in update libgomp (installed version is 4.8.5 4.el7 and with yum info I've seen the version 4.8.5 28.el7) but I'm not sure if it can cause problems in other parts of the system

Not sure if this is related to this site but any of you have seen anything like this?
Thanks

Server specifications:

- CentOS 7.0.1406
- Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
- PHP/5.6.26
- ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2016-06-16 Q16
- imagick 3.4.3

Comment: If ImageMagick was compiled/linked with OpenMP library, swapping `libgomp` may contribute to segfaults. Try recompiling IM with `--disable-openmp` flag to see if the problem goes away. (Run `convert -version | grep Features` to see if OpenMP is used.)

Comment: We have the same problem, using Official packages from Ubuntu.
https://serverfault.com/questions/966418/apache2-stops-after-system-graceful-restart